# Can't read a libsvm file in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, libsvm

I was trying to read a .txt file using Spark and pyspark and i get and error that I can't understand. I have py4j installed correctly and also i can read csv files with no problem.

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
my_data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("sample_libsvm_data.txt")
```

The error i got is this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3347b4cad068> in <module>
----> 1 my_data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("sample_libsvm_data.txt")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    164         self.options(**options)
    165         if isinstance(path, basestring):
--> 166             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    167         elif path is not None:
    168             if type(path) != list:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is your .py file and sample_libsvm_data.txt, absolute paths?

Comment: they are in the same folder under disk D.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue earlier. By setting "numFeatures" option resolved the issue.

```
my_data = spark.read.format('libsvm').option("numFeatures", "692").load('sample_libsvm_data.txt')
```

It will be difficult if numFeatures are not known. You can use this custom function to read libsvm file.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector

def read_libsvm(filepath, spark_session):
    '''
    A utility function that takes in a libsvm file and turn it to a pyspark dataframe.

    Args:
        filepath (str): The file path to the data file.
        spark_session (object): The SparkSession object to create dataframe.

    Returns:
        A pyspark dataframe that contains the data loaded.
    '''

    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        raw_data = [x.split() for x in f.readlines()]

    outcome = [int(x[0]) for x in raw_data]

    index_value_dict = list()
    for row in raw_data:
        index_value_dict.append(dict([(int(x.split(':')[0]), float(x.split(':')[1]))
                                       for x in row[1:]]))

    max_idx = max([max(x.keys()) for x in index_value_dict])
    rows = [
        Row(
            label=outcome[i],
            feat_vector=SparseVector(max_idx + 1, index_value_dict[i])
        )
        for i in range(len(index_value_dict))
    ]
    df = spark_session.createDataFrame(rows)
    return df
```

**Usage:**

```
my_data = read_libsvm(filepath="sample_libsvm_data.txt", spark_session=spark)
```